# Почему в Windows 10 не работает команда taskkill?

Tags: windows, процесс, командная-строка

Учусь работать через командную строку Windows. Застрял на процессах. Я смог запустить для примера калькулятор

```
 calc.exe
```

Теперь для тренировки хочу убить процесс разными способами. По имени

```
  taskkill /im calc.exe
```

По pid:

```
tasklist /v /fo list /fi "imagename eq calc*"
taskkill /pid 3920
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По имени образа с использованием фильтра

```
  taskkill /fi "imagename eq calc*"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему ни один из способов не сработал? Я, конечно, рад что

> Успех: Отправлен сигнал завершения процессу с идентификатором 3920.

Но где само завершение-то?

Comment: taskkill только отправляет процессу команду на завершение. Которую приложение может смело проигнорировать. К тому же калькулятор - это немножко не приложение, это магазиновский апплет. Попробуй то же, но с каким-нибудь "честным" приложением, которое стартует как дочка explorer.exe твоего сеанса (да хоть бы и блокнот) - и всё получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В новых Windows процесс калькулятора имеет имя "calculator.exe", а не "calc.exe". "calc.exe" - это обертка для обратной совместимости, а реальный процесс в другом приложении (UWP).

2. Чтобы завершить процесс принудительно, а не "отправить сигнал", используйте ключ /f:

```
taskkill /f /im calculator.exe
```